# generating pb file in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to generate a pb file using the method given in this tutorial,

http://cv-tricks.com/how-to/freeze-tensorflow-models/

```
import tensorflow as tf
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/Users/pr/tensorflow/dogs-cats-model.meta', clear_devices=True)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, "./dogs-cats-model")
```

When I try to run this code I get this error -

```
DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file ./dogs-cats-model: Data loss: file is too short to be an sstable: perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

WHen I googled this error most of them recommend to generate the meta file using version 2 format? Is that the right approach?

Tensorflow version used -

```
1.3.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you are using both '/Users/pr/tensorflow/dogs-cats-model.meta' and './dogs-cats-model.meta'. Are you sure they point to the same file?

The following code works well on my machine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./dogs-cats-model.meta', clear_devices=True)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, "./dogs-cats-model")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, im kinda confused, the import_meta_graph picks the meta file in that directory...What does the restore method does? It creates a dogs-cats-model file in that directory? When I checked in the directory I did not see it. Should the file name in the restore method should be the same?

Comment: `saver.restore` only restores variables in the current graph, so before you call `saver.restore`, you need to construct a graph with some variables, which is done by `tf.train.import_meta_graph` in this code. You can also explicitly define variables in your code as shown in this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model).